# How to hide dropdown when i was using 2 fields at a time?

Tags: javascript

I have two fields 1 is Simple Date picker and 2 is Custom Date picker and now i want to write a condition that if both the fields are used in one form then drop-down list was hide in Simple date picker field only.

i write this condition only for when i used only simple date picker fields in one form.

```
     document.getElementById("ddldate").style.display = "none";
```

now, i want to write condition for both the fields that are used in one form.

this is the picture of normal date picker and i want to remove this drop-down list if i use both custom date and simple date.

[image]

Comment: You used the tag vb.net but your question seems to be about JavaScript. You might consider changing the tag to 'JavaScript', otherwise your question may not get the attention you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clearly understood your question but i think you want some like below, You can check element exist or not in document using below code and then make your condition accordingly.

```
var date1=  document.getElementById('ddldate');
var date2=  document.getElementById('ddldate2');

if (date1 && date2)
{
   //do your stuff here i.e. hiding datepicker

   // document.getElementById("ddldate").style.display = "none";
}
```

Note: change element id as you have given in your form

Comment: Thank you for giving me answer but i did that another way.      $('.simpledate').hide();
$('.customdate').show();                                                                           i write this code in click event because there is issue of drop-down overlapping. but bdw thanks for your response.